# How to identify which of the two JComboBoxes has generated an itemchanged event?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a class which construct a GUI which has two `JComboBoxes`, `comboA` and `comboB` respectively. I have another class which handles the events of the componants on this GUI. I want to invoke two different methods on the `Itemchanged` event of each of the combobox.

I want to know that how could I identify on which of the two comboboxes event has occured?
How could I trace that which combobox's item has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set name of the combo box and check against their name.

Answer (score 4):

Every event object is associated with a source component. You'll need a reference to those components and perform a comparison to the component returned by [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

The ActionListener's actionPerformed(ActionEvent) method supplies a parameter of type ActionEvent. Ask the ActionEvent for the source of the event using its getSource() method. If the event is from one of your JCheckBoxes ist can be casted to that type and you may identify the source. Alternatively use two different ActionListener.